# what is the purpose of scoped slots in vuetify

Tags: vuejs2, vuejs3, vuetify.js

as far as I searched & learned, Slots permit to a parent component to inject content into a child component.
however I came accros an example using vuetify using **scoped slot**

```
    <template slot="content">
      <v-treeview
        :items="items"
        item-key="id"
        activatable
        open-on-click>
        <template #label="{ item }">
          <div @click="openFolder(item)">
          </div>
        </template>
      </v-treeview>
```

hence, I don't understand when to use scoped slot and for the current example where do **{ item }** which is passed to **#label** come from ? is it an iteration from array items (**:items="items"**) ?

Comment: Please add the `vue.js` tag, alongside the version-specific tags. And, if this is _not_ version specific, those tags are not necessary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Regular slot content does not have access to state in the child component. However there could be use cases where it could be useful if a slot's content can make use of data from both the parent scope and the child scope. To achieve that, we can make use of scoped slots.

```html
<!-- <MyComponent> template -->
<div>
  <slot :text="greetingMessage" :count="1"></slot>
</div>
```

```html
<MyComponent v-slot="slotProps">
  {{ slotProps.text }} {{ slotProps.count }}
</MyComponent>
```

See it in [vue sfc playgound](https://play.vuejs.org/#eNp9kMEKgzAMhl8l9OJlU3aVOhg7C3uAXsRlTtC2tFE2pO++dA5xMnZqk+b/8/2dxMnadBxQ5EL62rWWwCMN9qh021vjCMrn2fBNoya4OdNDkmarXhQnSstsVrOOC8LedhVhrEiuHca97wwVSsTj4oz1SvAUgKJpgqWZEj4IQoCvZm0Gtgghzss1BDvIbFkqdmID+CNdbbQnaBwitbop0fuqQSgguWPXmX+JePe1HT/QMtJBHnE51MZOCcjfzPx04JxsydPzp2Szxxo7vABY1I/p)

The props passed to the slot by the child are available as the value of the corresponding v-slot directive, which can be accessed by expressions inside the slot.

You can think of a scoped slot as a function being passed into the child component.

In the example you provided, the `items` feed into the `v-treeview` component are looped inside the component. Now if we wish to use each item but from the parent itself as you are intending to assign link for each label, then scoped slot are useful.

Read more about the scoped slots in the vue official documentation [here](https://vuejs.org/guide/components/slots.html#scoped-slots)

Comment: Please edit in some doc links. Makes an answer about this sort of thing a lot better :)

Comment: ok I understand that scoped slots permit to pass data from child to parent, but this part of your response isn't clear **Now if we wish to use each item but from the parent itself as you are intending to assign link for each label, then scoped slot are useful**
do you mean `v-treeview` has passed it back ? can you explain more ?

Comment: can you give an example of child comonent for my code ? (i.e illustrate how the data is passed)

Comment: yes absolutely. You can look inside the `v-treeview` component for reference where it loops with prop `items` and pass item to `v-treeview-node`. See https://github.com/vuetifyjs/vuetify/blob/dec99cfabdee1c052924b5bbd23ad7be44b7bac1/packages/vuetify/src/components/VTreeview/VTreeviewNode.ts#L189. Notice the `scopedProps` defined there. It's definition clearly has `item` property. See https://github.com/vuetifyjs/vuetify/blob/dec99cfabdee1c052924b5bbd23ad7be44b7bac1/packages/vuetify/src/components/VTreeview/VTreeviewNode.ts#L142

Comment: so I could have used leaf/ selected ... instead ? what would be the difference in their use ? when I should use one over an other ?

Comment: Not instead :) but `leaf` or `isSelected` could also be accessed from the parent component (eg: `<template #label={item, selected, leaf}">..</>`). If those values could serve your purpose, you certainely can use em.